# What is the route helper for Rails update action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I want to put a route helper in my form helper that goes to the `update` action:

```
<%= s3_uploader_form post: <route helper goes here>, as: "shop[logo_ori]" do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
<% end %>
```

but when I run `rake routes` I don't see a helper for `PUT`:

```
shops     GET    /shops(.:format)                     shops#index
          POST   /shops(.:format)                     shops#create
new_shop  GET    /shops/new(.:format)                 shops#new
edit_shop GET    /shops/:id/edit(.:format)            shops#edit
shop      GET    /shops/:id(.:format)                 shops#show
          PUT    /shops/:id(.:format)                 shops#update
```

The form helper in question comes from Railscasts#383's [source](https://github.com/railscasts/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3/blob/master/gallery-jquery-fileupload/app/helpers/upload_helper.rb). I found that the uploader form is pretty useful for creating a new model object but I'm struggling to get it to work for updating a model object.

When I tried the route helper `shops_url`, it runs a failed `POST` action:

```
Started POST "/shops" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-27 01:10:22 +0800
Processing by ShopsController#create as */*
Parameters: {"shop"=>{"logo_ori"=>"https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/example.gif"}}
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
<additional output redacted>
```

Any help?

Comment: `shops_url` looks ok, `ShopsController#create` is called. What is the error ?

Comment: @Baldrick I want it to point to the update action, not create.

Comment: The update route is *absolutely not*  the same as the create one, update is **POST /resources/id** when create is  **POST /resources**

what you want is `shop_path(shop)` or `shop_path(shop_id)`

Answer (score 5):

While HTTP and rack support the use of the PUT method, the browsers don’t. So in order to spoof a put request, you need to add a `_method=put` parameter to the url you'r posting to.

A link in rails would look something like:

```
<%= link_to "update me", "/link/to/resource", method: :put %>
```

Comment: Update: This is now done as a javascript call when using rails, so it is in fact a true HTTP PUT call.

Comment: Additional clarification: You still need to add the `method: :put` to your link.

Answer (score 3):

The same as for show - "shop_path", as it refers to the same URL. Different is only the method. Theese Rails route helpers are pointing only for urls, but not it's methods, that's why they are the same in this case.
By the way - the method should be "put:", not "post:" (as a param for your form helper)

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work. I'm beginning to suspect that it still points to the `CREATE` action because it uses jQuery $.post in the coffeescript: https://github.com/railscasts/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3/blob/master/gallery-jquery-fileupload/app/assets/javascripts/paintings.js.coffee